# I have a question about gifting on Steam

Tags: steam

Is it possible to purchase a second copy of a game on Steam that I already own and gift it to a friend?  If so, how do I?

Comment: Have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

After adding an item to your cart, you will see this screen. It will let you know you already own it and disable you from purchasing it again, so just select "Purchase as a gift" and follow the instructions.

[image: Steam store page]

Comment: The catch it that you can't gift the newer style of bundles; the older style bundles that can be gifted have been almost completely phased out by now.